# Difficulties with multiple scopes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have few images on which I wanna write some text using tikz. See the sample code below-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (a) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(a.south east)},y={(a.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {.\y};}
        \begin{scope}[x={(a.south east)},y={(a.north west)}]
            % draw something on image a
            \draw (.5,.5) node {Center of A};
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}

    \node (b) [below=of a] {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(b.south east)},y={(b.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {.\y};}
        \begin{scope}[x={(b.south east)},y={(b.north west)}]            
            % draw something on image b
            \draw (.5,.5) node {Center of B};
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please see the screenshot of generated PDF-

[image]

**The origin of the first scope is at the bottom left of the first image. but it isn't for the second image.**

Basically, there are following problems-

1. Notice that horizontal lines of the grid aren't rendered properly on the second image
2. The vertical lines of the gird on the second image are too long
3. The text corresponding to the grid didn't place properly

Comment: you also need to shift the scope's `(0,0)` to `b`

Comment: Also, for me the MWE doesn't produce the image shown.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I used `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2018.5.23)` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit PC.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you very much. I will check your suggestion soon!

Comment: Your second scope option should be `shift={(b.south west)},x={(b.south east)},y={(b.north west)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorporated the comments from [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) and [@Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit). Basically, the origin of the second scope wasn't set properly. In order to keep the consistency, I set the origin of all scopes. Please see the code snippet below-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0}]
    \node[anchor=south west] (a) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(a.south west)},x={(a.south east)},y={(a.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {.\y};}
        \begin{scope}[x={(a.south east)},y={(a.north west)}]
            % draw something on image a
            \draw (.5,.5) node[text=red, font=\Huge] {Center of A};
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}

    \node (b) [below=of a] {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(b.south west)},x={(b.south east)},y={(b.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} {\node[anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {.\y};}
        \begin{scope}[x={(b.south east)},y={(b.north west)}]            
            % draw something on image b
            \draw (.5,.5) node[text=red, font=\Huge] {Center of B};
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) and [@Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit).